# Update on list/dictionary works but I don't know why

Tags: python

I'm doing a tutorial and there's a fragment of code I don't understand. It updates a dictionary (item) but I don't understand why the main list (items) gets updated too.

It's the same thing when I filter my list with a lambda function or a for.

Could you explain me? Thanks in advance.

```
items = [{'name': 'toto', 'price': 99}]

name = 'toto'

#item = next(filter(lambda x: x['name'] == name, items), None)

for x in items:
    if x['name'] == name:
        item = x
    else:
        item = None


print(item)
if item is None:
    item = {'name': name, 'price': 77}
    items.append(item)
else:
    item.update({'price': 100})
print(item)
print(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `item` is not None, so the else clause updates the dictionary:

```
if item is None:
    item = {'name': name, 'price': 77}
    items.append(item)
else:
    item.update({'price': 100})
```

---

Your list has a single element in it, a dict. When you iterate over your list, you get references to your elements. Dicts are mutable, so you can change them.

Then item refers to the duct object (which is the only element in your list). Updating it changes its content. You can see item and your list points to the same element:

`id(item) == id(items[0])`

It is the same object, hence when you change it - your list item is changed as well.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I know that my item is not None. It's just that I don't understand why the line item.update also updates the list "items". Thanks.

Comment: @Koko I see. I've updated my answer, see if it helps you better understand this

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. Is this always the case? Do you know how I can create a new variable "item" that I can update without updating "items".